# How to prove $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}nx^n=0$ without L'Hôpital's rule, where $x \in [0,1)$??

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

How to prove $$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}nx^n=0$$ without L'Hôpital's rule? where $x \in [0,1)$ and $n=1,2,3,...$.

I know one of way to prove this is to treat $n$ is real, and $n$ and $(\frac{1}{x})^n$ as functions of $n$. Then, apply L'Hôpital's rule and it works for discrete $n$ by the definiation of limit.

However, I would like to skip the step we treat $n$ is real. Is there any proof for this question only using the techniques for limit of sequences? (such as the sandwich theorem, etc.)

Comment: Note that $\frac{(n+1)x^{n+1}}{nx^n}=\frac{(n+1)x}{n}=\left(1+\frac1n\right)x$

Comment: Assume that the limit is not 0. Consider the series $\sum_{n \geq 1}nx^n$ for all $x \in [0,1)$. Can you find a contradiction?

Comment: If you already know that $x^n\to 0$ then you can choose $N$ with $x^N\lt  \frac 12$

Then if $n=rN$ you are working with $nx^n\lt N\cfrac r{2^r}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $0 < x < 1$ we have $x = (1+y)^{-1}$ with $y > 0$.

It follows from the binomial theorem that,

$$ (1+y)^n > \frac{n(n-1)y^2}{2}.$$

Hence,

$$nx^n = \frac{n}{(1+y)^n}< \frac{2}{(n-1)y^2}.$$

For any $\epsilon > 0$, if $n > 1 + 2/(\epsilon y^2)$, then $|nx^n-0|= nx^n < \epsilon$.

Thus, $\lim_{n \to \infty} nx^n = 0$.

Answer (score 7):

Let $x<1-1/N$.  If $n>2N$ then $(n+1)x^{n+1}/(nx^n)<(1+\frac1{2N})(1-\frac1N)<1-\frac1{2N}$.  So terms from then on shrink by at least that factor, and $nx^n<C(1-\frac1{2N})^n\to0$.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint:** When $|x| < 1$ we have that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n x^n = \frac{x}{(x-1)^2}$$

Comment: I actually don't see how to easily prove this "from first principles" (i.e. by writing the finite sum and taking a limit). Starting from the finite version of the geometric series, I get $\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} n x^n = \frac{x}{(x-1)^2} - \frac{(N+1)x^N}{1-x}$, and sending $N \to \infty$ then requires the same limit as in the OP. I suppose you could prove the theorem about differentiation term-by-term, but that seems like fairly heavy machinery for this problem.

Comment: The idea is to calculate the taylor series of $\frac{x}{(x-1)^2}$.

Comment: Then you have to prove the Taylor series converges to $\frac{x}{(x-1)^2}$; just proving that it is convergent on $[0,1)$ is not enough. This requires either some real analysis trickery with the error formulae, or a foray into complex variables (where analyticity is "free" from differentiability).

Comment: Sure I'm aware of that, it answers the question on how to solve without L'hospital though.

Comment: @Ian: The question is only asking how to calculate the limit avoiding switching the discrete sequence $\{n\}$ to a function of $x$ and applying l'Hopital (he isn't asking for it to be proven from first principles).

Comment: But since the series converges for $|x|<1$, it must hold that $\{nx^n\}_{n=1}\rightarrow 0$ for $0<x<1$; as for $x=0$, it is trivial.

Comment: @hans__ The standard tricks to prove the series converges, like the ratio test, hinge on the limit we're trying to prove in the first place (or an equivalent one, like $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^{1/n}=1$). A better approach is to basically "rederive" the ratio test, which is what Michael did. (I wrote an answer to this effect, but removed it, since Michael's was just as effective and shorter).

Comment: "only using the techniques for limit of sequences"

Answer (score 3):

Let $0\lt x\lt 1$. Then there is a positive $a$ such that $x=\frac{1}{1+a}$. By the Binomial Theorem, we have for $n\ge 2$ that 
$$0\lt (1+t)^n =1+nt+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}t^2\gt \frac{n(n-1)}{2}t^2.$$
It follows that
$$0\lt nx^{n} \lt \frac{2}{t^2}\cdot \frac{1}{n-1}.$$
Now it is straightforward, given a positive $\epsilon$, to produce an $N$ such that $0\lt nx^n \lt \epsilon$ if $n\gt N$.

Comment: Pretty much identical to the accepted answer which was posted a minute later. (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Let $x \in ]0, 1[$ (the case where $x = 0$ is trivial). Since
$$
\frac{(n+1)x^{n+1}}{nx^{n}} = (1+\frac{1}{n})x \to x < 1,
$$
the series $\sum_{n} nx^{n}$ converges, so $nx^{n} \to 0$.

I hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

If $x\lt1$, then find $n_x$ so that $\frac1{n_x}\le\frac{1-x}2$. Then, for any $k\ge n_x$, $\frac1k\le\frac{1-x}2\implies x\le\frac{k-2}k$ and
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{(k+1)x^{k+1}}{kx^k}
&=\frac{k+1}kx\\
&\le\frac{k+1}k\frac{k-2}k\\
&=1-\frac1k-\frac2{k^2}\\
&\le\frac{k-1}k
\end{align}
$$
Thus, for any $n\gt n_x$,
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{nx^n}{n_xx^{n_x}}
&=\prod_{k=n_x}^{n-1}\frac{(k+1)x^{k+1}}{kx^k}\\
&\le\prod_{k=n_x}^{n-1}\frac{k-1}k\\
&=\frac{n_x-1}{n-1}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}nx^n
&\le\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n_xx^{n_x}(n_x-1)}{n-1}\\[6pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$
where the numerator is a fixed constant depending on $x\lt1$.

Comment: For $\rho$: $x<\rho<1$ it follows that $\frac{k+1}{k}x<\rho$ when $k>\frac{x}{\rho-x}$, which gives exponential convergence (your second line).

Comment: @A.G.: I was trying to avoid using $t^n\to0$ when $t\lt1$ since that seemed too close to the original question. It does mean faster convergence, but the speed of convergence is irrelevant here.